# Set the property of a control inside the RowStyle ->Template -> ControlTemplate -> Border of the DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Hi how can I set the property of a control placed inside a controltemplate. Here is my code:

```
                    <dg:DataGrid Name="questionList"
                             HeadersVisibility="None"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             Background="White"
                             Margin="42,32,43,0"
                             BorderThickness="0" 
                             GridLinesVisibility="None"
                             CanUserAddRows="False" 
                             HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFCCCCCC" 
                             Cursor="Hand" 
                             MaxHeight="483"
                             FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                             PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="questionnaireList_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
                             CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                             CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                             CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                             SelectionMode="Single">
                    <dg:DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </dg:DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding QuestionImage, Converter={x:Static my:StatusColorConverter.instance}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
                                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                            <dg:SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                                <dg:SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </dg:SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <dg:SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                </dg:SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <dg:DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                                                                           ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" 
                                                                           SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                                <Path Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                                   Data="M0,0.5 L1,0.5"
                                                                   Stretch="Fill" 
                                                                   Stroke="#FFCCCCCC" 
                                                                   StrokeThickness="1"
                                                                   StrokeDashArray="1.0 2.0"/>
                                                <Button Style="{DynamicResource btnSubmitStyle}" 
                                                        Width="106" 
                                                        Height="47" 
                                                        Name="btnSubmit"
                                                        Margin="0,13,0,13" 
                                                        Click="btnSubmit_Click" 
                                                        Visibility="Hidden" 
                                                        Grid.Column="3"
                                                        Cursor="Hand">
                                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                                <Image Source="/iQuestionnaire;component/Images/arrow.png" Width="17" Height="16" />
                                                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                                                                           FontSize="16" 
                                                                           Width="Auto"
                                                                           Text="Submit"/>
                                                            </StackPanel>
                                                </Button>
                                            </dg:SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="69*">
                            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="12,16,0,17" 
                                               FontSize="20" 
                                               Foreground="#0891F1" 
                                               Text="{Binding Path=QuestionNum}" 
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="601*">
                            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="14" 
                                               Foreground="#666666"
                                               Text="{Binding Path=QuestionDesc}"
                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                               TextAlignment="Justify"
                                               Margin="0,16,0,17" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="117*">
                            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=QuestionImage}" 
                                           Stretch="None" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                           Margin="0,16,18,17" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
                </dg:DataGrid>
```

I want to set the Visibility property of the "btnSubmit" button at run time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the Visibility of the 'btnSubmit' using  [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609059.aspx).

Just add to Resources:

```
<local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2vconv" IsReversed="false"/>
```

then use:

```
 Visibility="{Binding Path=yourDataSourceColumnWithBoolValueForVisibility, 
                      Converter={StaticResource b2vconv} }"
```